# Why does GCC 11.3.0 generate -Wformat warning on my x86_64 machine, but doesn't on godbolt x86_64 machine?

Tags: gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning, diagnostics

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
$ cat t56.c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    typedef struct { uint64_t v; } float64_t;
    union { double tf; float64_t f; } uX = {0};
    printf("%a [%lx]", uX.tf, uX.f);
}
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc t56.c -std=c11
t56.c: In function ‘main’:
t56.c:7:19: warning: format ‘%lx’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘float64_t’ [-Wformat=]
    7 |     printf("%a [%lx]", uX.tf, uX.f);
      |                 ~~^           ~~~~
      |                   |             |
      |                   |             float64_t
      |                   long unsigned int
```

Here we see that on my x86_64 machine GCC 11.3.0 generates `-Wformat` warning.

Let's compile the same code on godbolt x86_64 machine using GCC 11.3.0: https://godbolt.org/z/6hPTdsEb5

There we see that on godbolt x86_64 machine GCC 11.3.0 does not generate `-Wformat` warning.

Why does GCC 11.3.0 generate `-Wformat` warning on my x86_64 machine, but doesn't on godbolt x86_64 machine?

Extra question: are `GCC 11.3.0` and `GCC 11.3` the same versions?

Comment: One version or the other might have extra patches applied.  My distro applies their custom patchset to gcc releases, so it's not unheard of.

Comment: And godbolt emits the warning if you add `-Wformat`.  Your version just checks for that warning by default.

Comment: Add `-v` to the compiler flags both locally and on godbolt, and compare the output...